# Socket.io emit not working but doesn't throw error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, socket.io

I am trying to use sockets to make posts update don all users as soon as i create it it is a react app on localhost:3000 and node server on localhost:3000 here are my codes

File : socket.js

```
let io;
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

module.exports = {
    init:httpServer=>{
       io= new Server(httpServer, {
            cors: {
            //   allowedHeaders: ["socket.io"],
            //   credentials: true,
              methods: ["GET", "POST"],
              origin: "http://localhost:3000",
            },
          });
          return io;
    },
    getIo:()=>{
        if(!io) throw new Error("Socket.io is not initialized!");
        else return io;
    }
}
```

File app.js

```
mongoose
  .connect(URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database Connected!");
    const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log("server started 8080 port.");
    });

    const io = require('./socket').init(server);
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("connected via socket");
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  });
```

File where i create a post

```
const io = require("../socket")
exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("getting called createPost");
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const error = new Error("Validation failed,entered data is incorrect");
    error.statusCode = 422;
    throw error;
  }
  if (!req.file) {
    const error = new Error("No image Provided");
    error.statusCode = 422;
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(req.file);
  const imageUrl = req.file.path;
  const title = req.body.title;
  const content = req.body.content;
  let creator;
  const post = new Post({
    title: title,
    content: content,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    creator: req.userId,
  });
  post
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      // console.log(result);
      return User.findById(req.userId)
    
    }).then(user => {
      creator=user;
      user.posts.push(post);
      return user.save();
      
    }).then(result=>{
      io.getIo().emit('posts',{action:'create',post:post})
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Post created successfully!",
        post: post,
        creator:{_id:creator._id,name:creator.name}
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (!res.statusCode) res.statusCode = 500;
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    });
};
```

Frontend Code

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client'
 const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:8080');
      socket.on('posts',(data) => {
        if(data.action === 'create') {
          this.addPost(data.post)
        }
      });
```

Posts get added but i have to refresh which is not desired i am not getting errors please tell what i am doing wrong and how do i learn more thanks in advance

Comment: Your question says that your server is on 3000, but your client code connects to 8080.

Comment: FYI, this is really misleading: `const io = require("../socket")` because `io` is not the socket.io instance, it's your module exports object.  Probably not the cause of this issue, but very easy to get confused and make a mistake with.  It should probably be called something else that indicates its your module exports, not the `io` instance.

Comment: How is the `createPosts` route called from the client?  Is it a browser form post (that reloads the page)?